# How to compare row-wise the existence of each row of another matrix in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have two matrices, the first one is bigger (something like 400k entries), and the other 1k.

Both are n x 3 (rows x columns), storing 3D points (there are no repeated entries)

Just to illustrate, i can state them as (importing numpy as np, arbitrary values):

```
a = np.array([[1.1,2.2,3.3],[2.2,2.2,2.2],[1.1,1.1,1.1],[3.3,3.3,3.3],[4.4,4.4,4.4]])
```

and

```
b = np.array([[2.2,2.2,2.2],[4.4,4.4,4.4]])
```

Straightforwardly, i want this output:

```
>>array([False,True,False,False,True])
```

I'm just interested to know what rows in a are the b rows, not wich b row is or anything more complicated. So there's a native numpy (some kind of "np.compare_rowwise(b,a)" ) way of doing this?

Currently i'm using for loops, something like this:

```
for point in b:
    # 'occurance index' is the row index where point in b is equal
    occurence_index = np.where(np.all(a == point,axis=1))[0]
```

Actually it is working fine, but is awfully slow, and in a lot of post i read a lot of more experienced peopel saying: "avoid for loops in numpy"...

My real scenario is: I have a lot of Lidar point clouds (read with laspy, their XYZ coordinates are stored as "the big" n x 3 matrix), and I need to change the classification code (wich is stored as a one-dimensional numpy array) of some re-classified points (wich is "the less big" n x 3 matrix). With the one dimensional boolean array of occurence, i can easily can do "cloud.classification[occurrence_vector] = newclasscode".

So, how can I do this with numpy?

I'm really interested on solve my problem, i will accept any suggestions with any other fastest python tool.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this python snippet does the job for you.

[True if i.tolist() in [j.tolist() for j in b] else False for i in a]

Comment: thank you for answering, but i think that use lists will severely slow down the process...